# How to truncate text in this format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-jira

I'm trying to extract from this list

```
[<JIRA Issue: key='HDDIS-42214', id='855344'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key='HDDIS-42171', id='854930'>,
 <JIRA Issue: key='HDDIS-42170', id='854929'>]
```

the 3 strings:

```
HDDIS-42214
HDDIS-42171
HDDIS-42170
```

How can do this?

PS: At some point it can be 3, another 1, another 2...

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Yes, i have tried with strip, rstrip and lstrip but it gets the other part of the text and i need get only the fields inside key.

Comment: What you have doesn't look like text, it looks like a list. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes, sorry, i't s a list. If a reproduce the example of @ratnesh and i do print (res) it gives me an error:  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: You need to provide more information about what the list exactly contains (what is the `type` of the items). My guess would be [`repr` strings of `Issue` objects](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/main/jira/resources.py#L189) - but that's just a guess.

Comment: If the list contains `repr` strings, then it's missing quote characters (i.e. it's not a valid Python represent of a list and its contents).

Answer (score 1):

if your text is a list convert it to string using:

```
my_string = ','.join(your_list)
```

Below is python code

```
text = "[<JIRA Issue: key='HDDIS-42214', id='855344'>, <JIRA Issue: key='HDDIS-42171', id='854930'>, <JIRA Issue: key='HDDIS-42170', id='854929'>]"
import re    
m = re.findall("(?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)",text)
res = list()
for i in m:
   key = re.findall("(?<=key=')(.*?)(?=',)",i)
   res.append(key[0])
```

Your output would be:
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking or answering a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)